# In what mode does the 2960-S IOS prompt ends with a colon ":"

Tags: cisco, switch

### QUESTION

For a Cisco 2960-S switch, when connecting on the console port, normally the prompt is:

```
SwitchName>
```

then you issue an `enable` command and end-up with a prompt like:

```
SwitchName#
```

However, I stumbled to diagnostic a switch which was improperly booted with this prompt:

```
switch:
```

Note that the hostname wasn't shown, `switch:` is the exact prompt displayed, ending with a colon. I tried finding more information about this mode so that I can understand what happened and if it will happen again, but couldn't.

### ADDITIONAL CONTEXT

- there was a blinking-amber light on the front panel (I must admit I did not note which one, but it was one of the top ones, I think it could be RPS)
- this was following a power outage
- none of the ports had any indicators ON
- no command of my knowledge were recognized on that prompt
- I ended-up powering off twice the switch until it booted properly again
- I haven't been able to reproduce since

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The colon indicates that you've entered the switch bootloader.

There are [a few things](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12.2_55_se/commmand/reference/bootldr.html) you can do in this mode, the most popular I can think of is replacing a corrupted IOS image, which would be a good reason why you ended up there in the first place.

Comment: "bootloader mode" is then the cisco nomenclature for this mode

Comment: another good reason to be in the bootrom is to bypass the saved config on next boot. This is often times useful and used for password resets.

Answer (score 2):

You've most likely accidentally pushed the "Mode" button on the front-left of the switch while it was booting.  This will put the switch into "switch: mode", where you can perform functions such as password recovery, work with the flash, etc. -- see Cisco here:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps628/products_password_recovery09186a0080094184.shtml#topic1

You can type the command "boot" to reload the switch (or simply power cycle it), and it should then boot up normally.

-Rob.

Comment: If it was following a power outage, there's also a chance that a glitch on the console got interpreted as a break.